# Need to check this Discord "Exception"

Tags: discord

Today, while chatting in the server, I noticed this message in my DMs:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmxgS.png)

Is this real? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Seems like a new thing RIPE might be testing out, also got it.
Don't worry about it, I'm sure they'll post something on Twitter or something letting you know:)

Seems really cool tho

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).